# Page with unnecessary vertical scrollbar in Edge

Tags: html, css

I have a asp.net page with this body tag

```
<body style="margin-top:2px;margin-left:15px;overflow:auto;">
```

I get a vertical scrollbar although there is plenty of space left underneath the lowest point on the page.

In order to prove that there aren't any html elements that fool me in my perception of the page content and that cause the scrollbar, I added a Text mark "x" right before the  closure. This x is still 200px away from the page border.

Most strange: Once I set the margin-top to 0px then the scrollbar would disappear!! As if these 2 pixels on top were causing the overflow to happen!

I'm doing this rather ugly workaround that shifts the content 2 pixels down:

```
<body style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:15px;overflow:auto;">
<img src="img/transparent_dot.png" height="2" />
```

Comment: can you please put your code on jsbin.com, so we can look into it!

Comment: it's the margin-left pushing all to right, i guess

Comment: BloodyLogic: posting 900 lines of code? Would anybody have a closer look on such a complex page?

Comment: Joe RR: Why the margin-left tag? It's the margin-top tag. If I set it to 0px then the vertical scrollbar disappears. This is actually my ugly workaround. Set it to 0px and add: <img src="img/transparent_dot.png" class="DistanceKeeper" /> with height 2px

Comment: why do you use margin top on body?

Comment: Sfili_81 to control the gap between navigator border and content

Comment: Can you post your html ? i think it's not a good idea to put margin on body

Answer (score 0):

**You can make it auto-hiding instead of always-showing:**

*Try this*

```
html { -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;}
```